# Wait until Timer has elapsed until next instructions is executed

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

**Background:** first of all I know some of my code is messy, please don't hate me. Basically I want to animate the movement of a TextBox object on a Windows Forms window. I have managed to do this by using a `Timer`. However, the rest of my code executes whilst the timer is running (and so the TextBox is still moving). How do I stop this from happening.

Here is some of my code:

`move` method:

```
        private void move(int x, int y)
    {
        xValue = x;
        yValue = y;

        // Check to see if x co-ord needs moving up or down
        if (xValue > txtData.Location.X) // UP
        {
            xDir = 1;
        }
        else if (xValue < box.Location.X) // DOWN
        {
            xDir = -1;
        }
        else // No change
        {
            .xDir = 0;
        }

        if (yValue > box.Location.Y) // RIGHT
        {
            yDir = 1;
        }
        else if (yValue < Location.Y) // LEFT
        {
            yDir = -1;
        }
        else // No change
        {
            yDir = 0;
        }

        timer.Start();
    }
```

Timer `Tick` method:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        while (xValue != box.Location.X && yValue != box.Location.Y)
        {
            if (yDir == 0)
            {
                box.SetBounds(box.Location.X + xDir, box.Location.Y, box.Width, box.Height);
            }
            else
            {
                box.SetBounds(box.Location.X, box.Location.Y + yDir, box.Width, box.Height);
            }
        }
}
```

`move` calls:

```
        move(478, 267);
        move(647, 267);
        move(647, 257);
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to disable the timer prior to entering the while loop and when all tasks are finished, then set timer to enabled..

Comment: _"the rest of my code executes whilst the timer is running"_ -- the rest of what code? It appears you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (there are many `Timer` classes in .NET), and if so, nothing else will happen while the `while` loop is executing in the `Tick` event handler (not even updating the visual appearance of the window). It's not clear what other code might be running which would be a problem; given the code posted here, seems like you'd have the opposite problem (i.e. no other code would run)

Comment: Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem. State precisely and specifically what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: What I want it to do is run the while loop with the 478, 267 parameters and THEN the 647, 267 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but if you're trying to force the program to stop running code until the animation is done, you could try using async await.  You'll need at least .Net 4.5 to use async await, however.

```
private async void moveData(int x, int y)
{
    Variables.xValue = x;
    Variables.yValue = y;

    // Check to see if x co-ord needs moving up or down
    if (Variables.xValue > txtData.Location.X) // UP
    {
        Variables.xDir = 1;
    }
    else if (Variables.xValue < txtData.Location.X) // DOWN
    {
        Variables.xDir = -1;
    }
    else // No change
    {
        Variables.xDir = 0;
    }

    // Check to see if y co-ord needs moving left or right
    if (Variables.yValue > txtData.Location.Y) // RIGHT
    {
        Variables.yDir = 1;
    }
    else if (Variables.yValue < txtData.Location.Y) // LEFT
    {
        Variables.yDir = -1;
    }
    else // No change
    {
        Variables.yDir = 0;
    }

    await Animate();
}

private async Task Animate()
{
    while (Variables.xValue != txtData.Location.X && Variables.yValue !=     txtData.Location.Y)
    {
        if (Variables.yDir == 0) // If we are moving in the x direction
        {
            txtData.SetBounds(txtData.Location.X + Variables.xDir, txtData.Location.Y, txtData.Width, txtData.Height);
        }
        else // We are moving in the y direction
        {
            txtData.SetBounds(txtData.Location.X, txtData.Location.Y + Variables.yDir, txtData.Width, txtData.Height);
        }
        await Task.Delay(intervalBetweenMovements);
    }
}
```

This way it will wait for move(x, y) to complete before moving to the next line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)